# Get Activity Log in Linux

Tags: history

I don't know what was the size of files and in which folder they were put.but my little brother copied some files from one folder to another one.I am unable to get those files back.Is there any way so that I can get whole activity log of my computer? i.e. what was copied and where and all related information??

Comment: There is no information on that without some kind of a snapshot I am afraid. SIlly question, but you don't have a backup somewhere to create at least a file list, no matter if the files are outdated or not?

Comment: I am sorry but they were put in a truecrypt encrypted volume separately and file size were 20 GB so I had no option to upload all those files in the Google Drive or anywhere so I kept them in truecrypt volume and accidently he deleted them.please if you know how to get those files back,tell me.I tried recovery also.but I was unable.

Comment: If you open the TrueCrypt volume, aren't they still in trash by any chance?

Comment: NO I searched it but no option.And if more than 20 GB then system dont send them in trash I think.I am unable to find the file so I think he might have deleted them.

Comment: is there any way to know what activity was performed in the system so that I can know he deleted or copied or what.Like we know the history command works for all commands entered.

Comment: I am afraid nautilus doesn't keep track of actions like gnome-terminal as far as I know, but someone would have to confirm if there is no other way to somehow get useful information on that. Maybe look for files with a recent creation date (around the incident)?

Answer (score 0):

No,

there is no general activity log.

And it would not be easy to have one:

There are many places where files are affected. For a complete log, the logging would need to be implemented by the system level operations on files. But that would mean it would log many more irrelevant operations than useful operations.

Also, the log would contain lots of potentially private information, in file names, and in when something was done.

I do not expect it to be the case,
but there may be log stored by the specific application that was used to work with the files. (If you know which were used, add it to the question.)